# Print the odd number using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

The question is :

> The odd_numbers function returns a list of odd numbers between 1 and
> n, inclusively. Fill in the blanks in the function, using list
> comprehension. Hint: remember that list and range counters start at 0
> and end at the limit minus 1.

```
def odd_numbers(n):
    return [x for x in ___ if ___]

print(odd_numbers(5))  # Should print [1, 3, 5]
print(odd_numbers(10)) # Should print [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
print(odd_numbers(11)) # Should print [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
print(odd_numbers(1))  # Should print [1]
print(odd_numbers(-1)) # Should print []
```

And this is my code :

```
def odd_numbers(n):
    return [x for x in range(0, n) if x%2 != 0]

print(odd_numbers(5))  # Should print [1, 3, 5]
print(odd_numbers(10)) # Should print [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
print(odd_numbers(11)) # Should print [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
print(odd_numbers(1))  # Should print [1]
print(odd_numbers(-1)) # Should print []
```

The output of my code said :

> Here is your output:
> [1, 3] [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] [] []
>
> Not quite, odd_numbers(5) returned [1, 3] instead of [1, 3, 5].
> Remember that list comprehensions let us use a conditional clause.
> What's the condition to determine whether a number is odd or even?

i dont know which part i should add in my code, this python is new for me, can you help me?

Comment: So, the automatic test runner tried to explain to you what is wrong: "Not quite, odd_numbers(5) returned [1, 3] instead of [1, 3, 5]" Did you **read** this? Did you *try to understand the difference* between what your code did, and what it was supposed to do? Did you *try to think of a reason* why that happened? Did you *try testing the code directly yourself*? Did you try *testing individual parts*? Did you try *reading the documentation* (for example, by running `help(range)` at the Python interpreter prompt)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the range to take the n also.

```
def odd_numbers(n):
    return [x for x in range(0, n+1) if x%2 != 0]
```

Comment: omg, you right. i just realised it a moment ago that i should add +1 on it. thx btw

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, too, specifying a step to the range:

```py
def odd_numbers(n):
    return [x for x in range(1, n+1, 2) if x % 1 == 0]
```

Comment: Why even have the conditional?  It's always true.  `x % 1` is 0 for *any* number.

Answer (score 0):

```
def odd_numbers(n):
    return [x for x in range(1, n+1) if x % 2 ==1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def odd_numbers(n):
    return [x for x in range(0,n+1) if x%2 > 0 ]
```

This worked for me as well but I'm not sure which is best practice when testing for an odd value (!= 0 or > 0). So which option is best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of losing one iteration as proposed previously by starting from 0 as in:

```
def odd_numbers(n):
    return [x for x in range(0, n+1) if x % 2 != 0]
```

start from 1 to speed up:

```
def odd_numbers(n):
    return [x for x in range(1, n+1) if x % 2 != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def odd_numbers(n):
    return [x for x in range(1,n+1) if x % 2 ==1]

print(odd_numbers(5))  # Should print [1, 3, 5]
print(odd_numbers(10)) # Should print [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
print(odd_numbers(11)) # Should print [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
print(odd_numbers(1))  # Should print [1]
print(odd_numbers(-1)) # Should print []
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this also works

```
def odd_numbers(n):
    return [x for x in range(0, n+1) if x % 2 == 1]
```